# Is this graphical visualization correct?

Tags: deep-learning, matconvnet

I am new in deep learning and trying to draw the fcn32 architecture (Figure 3 in [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf)) based on my design and shapes. Could you please have a look on schematic of FCN32 architecture and let me know if some parts need to be corrected?Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

The architecture looks correct. You can use [this](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/editor) website to visualize networks which are written in Caffe prototxt format. The prototxt for FCN32s is [here](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/train.prototxt).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, That website is amazing :). Indeed, I am designing by my own graphical shapes, because I have to document the models. Thanks a lot once again